# It's good to use framesets in html/php pages?

Tags: php, html, frame

I'm new in php and html scripting, so I would like to know if someone could give me an advice about how to set up my page structure.

I need to create a page with an header and a footer, a left-page menu and a main section where the contents of the site are displayed.

I thought about a frameset like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//IT” “http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd”>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=iso-8859-1?>
<title>Framesets</title>
</head>

<frameset rows=”20%,70%,10%”>
<frame src=header.php>
     <frameset cols=”20%,80%”>
     <frame src=menu.php>
     <frame src=main.php>
    </frameset>
 <frame src=footer.php>
</frameset>
<noframes></noframes>
</html>
```

When someone click on a link displayed on the menu.php section, only the main.php section will be called with different options (or I can call different php pages, one per choice), but I'm not sure this is the best solution, can anyone give me some advices?

(sorry for my english!)

Comment: It is good if it is 1995 on your calendar

Comment: @zerkms he was kiddin...

Comment: PS: curious why people often sorry for their English, but never sorry for their code :-S

Comment: I think they were being sarcastic.  Framesets are generally considered to be archaic in HTML development these days.

Comment: @alfasin: Right, I failed sense of humour test :-(

Comment: At the risk of coming of as snarky: how the hell did you even came across framesets? Last time I checked we ware in 2012 not early nineteen's.

Comment: @zerkms many good programmers fail it (cause of logic thinking) - you're in a good company! :)

Comment: <FONT SIZE="7"><BLINK>What is wrong with framesets?</BLINK></FONT>

Comment: thanks to everyone! I know I'm a newbie in html/php so I understand why a lot of you can complain about my code (expecially for you zerkms, I apologize :))! I'll try without frames :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you really don't need frames,
maybe rather try something like this for this kind of page layout:

http://jsfiddle.net/YAxQM/

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <?php include('header.php') ?>
</header>
<div class="main">
  <nav>
   <?php include('menu.php') ?>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <?php include('main.php') ?>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <?php include('footer.php') ?>
</footer>​
```

**CSS**

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;  
}
header{
   height: 20%;
}
.main{
   height: 70%;
}
footer{
   height: 10%;
}
nav{
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I'll try without frames :)

Answer (score 6):

No, it's not good.

The use of HTML framesets has been deprecated and is no longer valid in recent versions of HTML.

You can still use `<iframe>` if you need this kind of feature, but in general what you're trying to do is a very *very* out-dated way of writing web pages.